# Moving exportPDF function from page to a helper class, replacing 'this'. in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, class, webforms

I have an ASP.NET web application in which I created a folder called Code. In this folder is my Basepage.cs. I also added a class called Reporting.cs which will have a static function called ExportReport. When I move the working function from my asp.net page to the Reporting.cs class the keyword 'this.' is erroring out:

```
    this.Response.Clear();
    this.Response.ContentType = result.MimeType;
    this.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
    this.Response.Expires = -1;
    this.Response.Buffer = true;

    this.Response.BinaryWrite(result.DocumentBytes);
    this.Response.End();
```

Before 'this' refered to the current page class I was in of type (System.Web.Page). Now I don't have that anymore so how would I use the response methods?

Comment: Please add the whole Exception

Comment: Typically the page itself would be responsible for writing the content to the output, and the helper class would only be responsible for generating the PDF. Follow the singular purpose principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are describing wanting to use an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

The signature of the method should end up looking something like below (I don't know what return type you want the method to have, so I chose void just to have something):

```
static public class Reporting
{
    . . .
    static public void ExportReport(this BasePage page)
    {
        . . .
    }
}
```

The body of `ExportReport` would then replace uses of `this` with `page`.

```
page.Response.Clear();
page.Response.ContentType = result.MimeType;
page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
page.Response.Expires = -1;
page.Response.Buffer = true;

page.Response.BinaryWrite(result.DocumentBytes);
page.Response.End();
```

**Calling approach one, as though the extension method were a method on the instance**

Calling extension methods this way is simple, having to do with the fact that extension methods are meant to be callable as though they were methods available on the instance of the class they are extending.  So if you have an instance, you do `instance.ExtensionMethod()` and do not have to put the instance as a parameter of the call, because you are using the instance to make the call.

If you have an instance of a `BasePage`, in a variable called `page`, you can then call the extension method like this:

```
page.ExportReport();
```

If your `ExportReport` has three parameters in its signature, then you'd call it like this:

```
page.ExportReport(param2, param3);
```

Note how I moved the first parameter to before the method.

**Calling approach two, just like calling a normal static method**

Since extension methods are static methods, you can also call them in normal static method style.

So, if you have an instance of `BasePage` named `page` (or `this` within a `BasePage` method, you can call like so:

```
Reporting.ExportReport(page, param2, param3)
```

param2 and param3 are examples, if you have extra parameters, which your comment indicates.  Use however many extra parameters you have, obviously.

**Summary**

These two calling approaches mean that from within a `BasePage` method you could call in two ways, since `this` within a `BasePage` method will refer to the `BasePage` instance itself:

```
this.ExportReport(param2, param3);
```

Or

```
Reporting.ExportReport(this, param2, param3);
```

So, an extension method will handle what you want to do nicely, allowing both a syntax that looks like the extension method is an extra method available on `BasePage` instances, or also a regular static calling style.

However, you can also use a regular static method, without the extension method's 'syntactic sugar', in which case the first parameter of your signature won't have a `this` in front of it.  But the extension is nice, because you can make it look like an extra method available on your `BasePage`, and do `page.ExportReport` or even `this.ExportReport` from within `BasePage` methods.

Comment: So your saying I would have to pass the page as a parameter and that is the only way right?

Comment: my function declaration now looks like the following and I think its good to go: protected static void ExportReport (System.Web.UI.Page page, Type report, string name, string[] reportParams, bool isAttachment = false). Even if my pages inherit from a base page it shouldn't affect this right?

Comment: You can then call the extension method by doing `page.ExportReport();`  I'll update to show that.

Comment: Oh I see what you saying. I actually don't want it to be an extension method but to be called more like this: Reporting.ExportReport(params).

Comment: You can certainly do that.  Then you just pass page as the first parameter in a normal way.  So you are just looking for a static method that receives a bunch of parameters, and the first parameter is an instance of `BasePage`.

Comment: However you can use the extension method do what you want, too.  I'll write a second update.

Comment: Did some updates.  You're proposed sigature could then look like `public static void ExportReport (this System.Web.UI.Page page, Type report, string name, string[] reportParams, bool isAttachment = false)` and you can call it one of two ways as described.